# Ajax post jSon data in Request object

Tags: request, http-post, asp.net-ajax

I am passing a json data using jQuery to a Ajax call. I want to read this json in my Application_BeginRequest function on global.ascx for some puspose. 
Where can i find this data in "Request" object.
I found that the Questystring and the Form of Request object. both are empty.

Calling ajax function as below using jQuery

Regards

Umesh

```
var inputData = "{'ID':'" + ID + "', 'Code':'" + Centre +"'}";

var pageURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + 
    "/webmethod.aspx/MyFunction"
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: pageURL,
    data: inputData,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
```

Comment: In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Add HTML, and everything required to duplicate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**P.S -** Assuming you want to post the `json` data using `**jquery**` to your **`ASPX`** page, Adding a sample below.

```
function GetEmployee()
    {
        var jsonObj = {"Org":0 ,"Dept":0,"Desg":0,"Grp":0,"SubGrp":0,"Loc":0,"Prv":'CanViewEmployee',"CustAttrId":0,CustAttrVal:"","Status":'1' };
        $.ajax({
            url: 'EmployeeSearchControl.aspx/populateJsonResult',
            datatype: 'json',
            data:JSON.stringify(jsonObj),
            method: 'Post',
            success: function (data) {
                if(data != null || data != "")
                {
                    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
                    {
                        addEmployeeToGrid(data[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }


 public class JSONRequest
    {
        public long Org { get; set; }
        public long Dept { get; set; }
        public long Desg{ get; set; }
        public long Grp { get; set; }
        public long SubGrp { get; set; }
        public long Loc { get; set; }
        public long Cat { get; set; }
        public string Prv { get; set; }
        public long CustAttrId { get; set; }
        public string CustAttrVal { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            string ap = Request["org"];
            HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
            string jsonString = "";
            using (StreamReader inputStream = new StreamReader(this.Request.InputStream))
            {
                jsonString = inputStream.ReadToEnd();
            }
            JSONRequest masterDetails = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JSONRequest>(jsonString);
}
```

Hope it helps. Please let me know if you require any other help.